# Multipage TIFF image file created in .NET Framework has bigger size

Tags: c#, tiff, filesize, multipage

I created windows service in c# (.net framework 4.0) for multipage TIFF files creation.
Windows servis is monitorig directories and merges or divide single page Tiff files in directories to multipage TIFF files.  Service is running on Windows 2012 server.

When I open and then save TIFF file created by mentioned service in another image application (e.g. Irfan). The saved file has smaller size. In Irfan I save it with same resolution and compression as is in original file. When I compare properties of files in explorer they have same dimension, dpi and compression type.

e.g. my multipage Tiff file created in .NET has 426kB and when I open and save the same file in Irfan it has 407kB after that. It is about 20kB difference. For only one file it is not important, but I have 6 hundred thousand files in directory :(

For TIFF creation I'm using System.Windows.Media.Imaging it should be better then  System.Drawing.Imaging (GDI+).

...

```
// load frontside of document
decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource,BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

bitmapSourceFrontSide = decoder.Frames[currentFrame];

// load backside of document

//...

encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4;

CroppedBitmap tiffPage;

//...

// TIFF image can be divided to multipage tiff
tiffPage = new CroppedBitmap(bitmapSourceFrontSide, new Int32Rect(pagePosition, 0, pageFrameWidth, (int)bitmapSourceFrontSide.PixelHeight));

encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(tiffPage));

if (bitmapSourceBackSide != null)
 {
 tiffPage = new CroppedBitmap(bitmapSourceBackSide, new Int32Rect(pagePosition, 0, pageFrameWidth, (int)bitmapSourceBackSide.PixelHeight));

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(tiffPage));
 }

//... created and add all pages to tiff file let's save it

using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create))
{ 
 encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

Do you have idea why TIFF file created in .NET has bigger size?

Thank you

Comment: It is possible that .net adds additional metadata to the file. Images like tiff has a metadata section that is used for number of things like GPS info etc. If you run on a optimizer it should reduce the size ofthe file i.e. remove the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using `BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat` and `TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4`.
MSDN say about [TiffCompressOption Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffcompressoption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The Ccitt3, Ccitt4, and Rle require that the PixelFormat value be set
>   to BlackWhite. Setting the PixelFormat to any other value resets the
>   Compression property value to Default.

Maybe this is happening? Are the images B/W? If not try using `Lzw` or `Zip` explicitly to see if they work better on your images than the default the system decides to use!

Also, imo, a difference of 5% is not really something to get upset about. What it means is that instead of 600,000 images you can only hold 570,000 images.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that difference is in the internal structure of TIFF file created from .Net Framework.

I compared TIFF tags and file structure created in .Net Framework and other applications (Irfan and LibTff.NET) and .NET Framework internally dived TIFF file to different count of Strips and rows. It is probably internal implementation of Tiff encoder and developer can't change it. It has no effect on image quality but file could be slightly bigger.

The main differences in files are in the following structures:

### StripByteCounts

- Tag  = 279  (117)Hex
- Type = word or dword
- N    = StripsPerImage for PlanarConfiguration equal to 1.     =
  SamplesPerPixel  * StripsPerImage  for PlanarConfiguration equal to 2
- No default.

For each strip, the number of bytes in that strip.  The existence
of  this   field  greatly   simplifies  the  chore  of  buffering
compressed data, if the strip size is reasonable.

### StripOffsets

- Tag  = 273  (111)Hex
- Type = word or dword
- N    = StripsPerImage for PlanarConfiguration equal to 1.     =
  SamplesPerPixel  * StripsPerImage  for PlanarConfiguration equal to 2
- No default.

For each  strip, the  byte offset  of that  strip.  The offset is
specified with  respect to  the beginning of the TIFF file.  Note
that this  implies that  each strip has a location independent of
the locations  of other  strips.   This feature may be useful for
editing applications.  This field is the only way for a reader to
find the image data, and hence must exist.

### RowsPerStrip

- Tag  = 278  (116)Hex
- Type = word or dword
- N    = 1
- Default is  2**32 -  1, which  is effectively infinity.  That is, the
  entire  image is  one strip.
- Recommended is a strip size of 8K.

The number  of rows  per strip.  The image data is organized into
strips for  fast access  to individual  rows  when  the  data  is
compressed - though this field is valid even  if the  data is not
compressed.

Tags description was used from
http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm